# Ruby/Rails - Active Record Db Migration to MySQL - timestamp type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Redmine and when I run a rake db migration the database gets created in mysql ok. My problem is that the date field is wrong. **I want it to be a mysql timestamp type, but instead it is a DATETIME type in MySQL**.

```
class CreateChats < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :chats do |t|
      t.column :message, :string
      t.column :user, :integer
      t.column :sendDate, :timestamp
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :chats
  end
end
```

In addition if I make a change to this migration how do I get it to remake the table (deleting it doesn't work)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always insert a column with a custom type if you want. The symbol names are automatically converted into whatever ActiveRecord defines, but if you use a plain string it goes in as-is:

```
t.column :ar_timestamp, :timestamp
t.column :mysql_timestamp, 'timestamp'
```

What you get is `ar_timestamp` being the usual `DATETIME` type where `mysql_timestamp` is defined as `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Thank you. For the migration I figured out one just has to increment the version of the migration in the db folder.

Comment: If you want to re-run the migration try `db:migrate:redo`