# Making ActiveRecord / Rails use actual mysql TIMESTAMP columns

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, timestamp

Rails' `:timestamp` column type lies; it's actually just an alias for `:datetime`.

I'm using mysql, and I want to use actual unix-timestamp `TIMESTAMP` columns.

a) Is there a nice way to set this, other than just making the column using SQL?

b) Will ActiveRecord cope with it properly (e.g. converting to `Time` when necessary, accepting a unix timestamp `Integer` as input, etc)? What gotchas should I expect to have to handle, and where?

Why:

1. Speed. This is for an extremely active table that's aggregating outside data sources that already use unix timestamps. Converting to datetime (or even converting first to a db string, which goes through 2 `gsub`s) uses up the majority of its import time. I could otherwise be doing just a dirt cheap `Integer#to_s` call.
2. Timezones. I don't want 'em. I want it stored timezone-agnostically; dealing with timezones is a pain and is completely irrelevant to my needs except at the very final stage before individual user display. The data itself has no need to know what timezone it was recorded in.
3. Size. It's a large table. [TIMESTAMP is half the size of DATETIME.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html)

Yes, I would still be doing `updated_at` calculations in code, not mysql. That part isn't a bottleneck.

Why your 'why not' is wrong (preëmptively, to show I'm not asking for noobish reasons :-P):

1. "But TIMESTAMP auto updates": [That's only true by default, and can be easily switched off.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html)
2. I'm actually not using Rails, just ActiveRecord.
3. Yes, this is based on [actual profiling data](https://plus.google.com/u/0/103112149634414554669/posts/EGghnZ1icVY); I am not early optimizing. `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter#quote` (in `Quoting#quoted_date` [if passing `Time`] or `Mysql2Adapter#quote_string` [if preconverting `to_s(:db)`]) is actually the most CPU-consuming section of my scraper. I want rid of it.

Comment: Why would it matter if you are using Rails (#2)? (I'm using Rails, but considering using timestamp to save space.)

Answer (score 8):

this works (just added whitespace character to type definition, so :timestamp doesn't override it):

```
     t.add_column :sometable, :created_at, 'timestamp '
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty noobish, but I'll give it a shot. What if you were to add your own custom column, or overwrite the default ones? You can use custom data types with a string like so:

```
t.add_column :mysql_timestamp, 'timestamp'
```

and then somewhere else in your logic

```
def mysql_timestamp
  Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end
```

Not sure about b). Only one way to find out!

Comment: 'timestamp' column type is not TIMESTAMP, it's DATETIME.

Comment: only when it's a symbol. if you use a string it can be whatever you want it to be, at least, according to @tadman in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100209/ruby-rails-active-record-db-migration-to-mysql-timestamp-type#4100341 I haven't tried it though.