# migrate "column" : timestamp is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I was creating a model, I made a column edited:timestamp.

```
t.timestamp :edited # in migration file
```

Was expecting that whenever user edits anything in this model, the time/date will be updated.

But I just saw that in database schema it is written down as

```
t.datetime "edited"
```

and it expects user to enter data in a form.

What's happening here?

How should I change my migration file to make a timestamp column in SQL DB? Or I should assign it in the model itself?

I don't want it to depend on user input, has to be a system cell

thx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create a model, you should then generate a ActiveRecord migration to create the table that will store the data associated with this model. For example, if your model is called 'Product', run:

```
rails g migration create_products_table
```

this will generate a migration file in db/migrate (prefixed with the timestamp at which you generated the migration file, eg: "20121201200720_create_products_table.rb")

The migration file should look like this:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When you run this migration (`rake db:migrate`), ActiveRecord will automatically create two columns in your table : `created_at` and `updated_at`. Then go and have a look at your schema.rb (in db). There will be something like that:

```
create_table "products", :force => true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end
```

`created_at` will store the timestamp at which the product was created.
`updated_at` will store the timestamp at which the product was last updated (what you're looking for here)

So you don't have to create a custom column, you should just rely on ActiveRecord's built-in timestamps.

Comment: so easy.. thanks. I'm just a newbie - didn't know Rails can create them for me

Answer (score 1):

Rails, more specifically, ActiveRecord was made to be database agnostic. This is great when looking to migrate applications or deploy them using different databases, stacks, etc. However one of the limitations it imposes is AR doesn't support any database-specific functionality.

The list of AR column types can be found [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column). As you can see, "timestamp" is an AR column type but it's more of an alias for the "datetime" type.

So if you want to use a real SQL timestamp column in your application, you can do one of two things:

1. You can edit the migration file and try `t.edited "TIMESTAMP"' (not tested but should work, since AR allows custom types as strings)
2. You can create the column in the database and allow AR to pick it up.

If you are new to rails, then I would strongly suggest using Gullaume Galuz's answer and let AR take care of the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

If not, you can also take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227784/making-activerecord-rails-use-actual-mysql-timestamp-columns) will clearly elucidates a need to use the DB specific `TIMESTAMP` column. (size, speed, zones, etc)