# ActiveRecord Migration - datetime to timestamp

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to migrate some datetime columns in MySQL to timestamp type. In ActiveRecord migration I have:

```
change_column(:oe_tags, :created_on, :timestamp)
```

however the sql it generates is

```
ALTER TABLE `oe_tags` CHANGE `created_on` `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

which is obviously NOT a timestamp type, but rather datetime (which it already is). How do I get an alteration to `timestamp`? According to the documentation :timestamp is a valid symbol.

Edit: 
Perhaps I did not make myself clear (apologies). I would like to know the proper change_column specification in ActiveRecord migration in Rails. I already KNOW the proper SQL I expect. How to achieve it via an ActiveRecord Migration is the question.

Comment: Maybe you'll find some answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227784/making-activerecord-rails-use-actual-mysql-timestamp-columns, it's very similar to your question

Comment: Thanks @AdrienK - that is exactly what I needed. Not sure how you located that - I searched first and didn't see it.

Answer (score -2):

Try the `modify` keyword ::

```
ALTER TABLE `oe_tags` MODIFY `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL
```

Comment: This does not create a timestamp - it creates a datetime type.