# Rails ActiveRecord Timestamp in Epoch instead of DateTime Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Need to store created_at and updated_at timestamps in Epoch instead of DateTime Format. Is there a way to alter the default behaviour, while having ORM to do it's job to maintain the timestamp.

When I use Rails Generator to generate my models

```
class CreateTenants < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :tenants do |t|
      t.string :tenant_name
      t.string :tenant_owner_name
      t.string :tenant_address
      t.string :tenant_email
      t.integer :pincode

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Not the timestamp that translates to DateTime.

```
create_table "tenants", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string   "tenant_name"
    t.string   "tenant_owner_name"
    t.string   "tenant_address"
    t.string   "tenant_email"
    t.integer  "pincode"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  end
```

I know that I can directly create two columns, and manually alter the created_at and updated_at fields everytime the record is added/changed, But that's going to be lots of bad code redundant code introduced in the application.

What I need is to somehow store the timestamps in epoch format (Time since 1970 in Long) instead of DateTime.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just defining your `created_at` and `updated_at` columns as `timestamp` columns in your schema?

Comment: Yes. But by default it take sql datetime format. But i want to store it as Epoch instead of DateTime

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I don't understand what you mean by Epoch. I thought you meant storing the columns as seconds since 1970 and that, I am guessing, could just work if you defined the columns as `timestamp` columns. Could you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified the DB used, so I assume MySQL here. It turns out Rails supports all variants of date/time columns for the timestamps: `DATE`, `TIME`, `DATETIME`, `TIMESTAMP` and even `INTEGER`. See the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) for more info about the differences between these types and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3929047/1544012) for info about how Rails understand them.

**1) `TIMESTAMP` timestamp columns**

If you want to store the timestamps **in `TIMESTAMP` type columns**, try the following trick in your migration (note the space in `'timestamp '`, it is [needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227784/making-activerecord-rails-use-actual-mysql-timestamp-columns) otherwise Rails will always create the column as `datetime` instead - `timestamp` is only an alias for `datetime` in Rails):

```
create_table :tenants do |t|
  # ...

  #t.timestamps (remove the default timestamps definition) 
  t.column :created_at, 'timestamp ', null: false
  t.column :updated_at, 'timestamp ', null: false
end
```

When working with the records, the timestamps will appear as a usual datetimes but will be stored as `TIMESTAMP`s in the DB, thus saving a few bytes per record:

```
Tenant.create!
# => SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO `tenants` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2016-06-08 08:45:20', '2016-06-08 08:45:20')
=> #<Tenant id: 1, tenant_name: nil, tenant_owner_name: nil, tenant_address: nil, tenant_email: nil, pincode: nil, created_at: "2016-06-08 08:45:20", updated_at: "2016-06-08 08:45:20">
```

Of course, you can always convert a datetime to seconds since the Epoch using the `to_i` method:

```
Tenant.last.created_at.to_i
# => 1465375595
```

**2) `INTEGER` timestamp columns**

If you want to store the timestamps indeed **as seconds since the Epoch** (1970), just define the timestamp columns as `INTEGER` type columns:

```
create_table :tenants do |t|
  # ...

  #t.timestamps (remove the default timestamps definition)
  t.integer :created_at, null: false
  t.integer :updated_at, null: false
end
```

Then, the timestamps in the records also appear as integers in Rails:

```
Tenant.create!
# => SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO `tenants` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (1465375595, 1465375595)
# => #<Tenant id: 1, tenant_name: nil, tenant_owner_name: nil, tenant_address: nil, tenant_email: nil, pincode: nil, created_at: 1465375595, updated_at: 1465375595>
```