# Preventing Rails 4 migration from changing timestamp to datetime?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have created a rails schema by pulling it out of an existing database.  So now I want to migrate that schema so I can duplicate my tables on a test database.  However, even though my schema and migration files have tables with timestamp attributes

e.g.

```
t.timestamp "column_name", limit: 6,
```

When I do

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

The timestamp columns are changed in the sql:

```
`column_name` datetime(6)
```

I don't want to change the column type to datetime and I realize that setting limits on datetime is an error in mysql.  Is there a way I can force rails to migrate using timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, As far as ActiveRecord is concerned `timestamps == datetime`. so when you call `t.timestamp` it created an column with type as `datetime`. AR doesn't seem to use MYSQL's TIMESTAMP datatype. [here is the relavent source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L710).

```
  def add_timestamps(table_name)
    add_column table_name, :created_at, :datetime
    add_column table_name, :updated_at, :datetime
  end
```

As you may note above, rails is creating two columns with `datetime` datatype instead of timestamp. so you will have explicitly specify the column type like this:

```
t.column, :timestamp, "column_name", limit: 6
```

Comment: what about mysql 5.1?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to define a column specifying the type as a string which will just use that type definition in the database rather than applying any rails interpretation on it. The [column docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column) suggest this but also warn "...this will not be database agnostic and should usually be avoided". It appears that in your case that isn't a problem though.

So, something like the following should work:

```
t.column "column_name", "timestamp"
```

This is also suggested by this answer : [Ruby/Rails - Active Record Db Migration to MySQL - timestamp type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100209/ruby-rails-active-record-db-migration-to-mysql-timestamp-type) . I wasn't sure that it would still be the case with later versions of rails but it still seems to hold true.